# Change select button on selection of another select button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am a beginner. I dont know Ajax. In my project I am using JSP as its front end tool and mysql as its back end. I want to change a select button when another select button value changes.

For Example suppose I have a table course and subject

Table:Course

```
cid    course
 1       MCA
 2       BCA
 3       Bsc Mathematics
```

Table:Subject

```
sid    subject   scode    cid
 1       SE      mca01     1
 1       SAD     mca02     1
 3       SE      bca01     2
 4       Java    bca05     2
```

I want to display the subjects SE and Java When BCA is selected from another select box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Comment: JSP is also your back-end, it's the server-side language. MYSQL is simply how you're storing the data on the back-end. Front-end = Client-side.